# Magento Blank/White Screen for specific IP Address

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I am using Magento-1.9 version. I cant login at the back end with the IP address of my workplace.
But at home it is working and for other networks also working.

I get a blank/white screen after login.
I've tried to clean cache and browser settings everything.

In the var files i don't have error log. I upgraded my magento version 1 year ago.

This is what i see in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK] RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

Comment: I use magento 1.9

Comment: check error log or browser console?

Comment: Have you upgraded version recently ?

Comment: Hello, @Magenx i checked but nothing what i can see.
In the var files i dont have error log

Comment: @MagentoDeveloper no almost 1 year ago.

Comment: Everyone can login, but on my network at work it isnt possible :S

Comment: @EbubekirAksu Okay you can see your.htaccess file. And search for, RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}

Comment: @EbubekirAksu to check wheather any speciffic IPs are blocked

Comment: Dear @MagentoDeveloper,

This is what i see

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution.

AMASTY ERROR EXTENSION !

i was on the blacklist unfortunately.

Comment: Good. This my also help others. But think again once, because the extension is not free version !

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh cache of your magento

Comment: This is not an answer.